# When changing html in nginx default document root, nothing changed in web browser

Tags: html, nginx

I created EC2 instance and installed Nginx. And I checked Nginx was running and the welcome phrase in web browser. However, when I added only few words in  index.html in /usr/share/nginx/html, nothing changed in web browser. No changes happened in web browser. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you may want to post your nginx config.

Usually you have to define your `root /some/absolute/path;` statement otherwise it will use the default one.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root